# Looking for FpML best practices

Tags: programming, fixed-income, portfolio-management, order-handling

We want start using FpML within our organisation; where message will be sent using FpML.

- What are best practices to do this ?
- If anyone who have used Tools as well as; i want to use FpML for messaging as well as capturing trade details...

Comment: http://www.fpml.org/dev/modules/newbbex/